# New pop up window that closes upon completion?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio

It seems I've got a question so basic no one's asked it yet. I want a button to open a new popup window with some input controls (labels and textboxes), and then for the window to close upon submission of the input by a submit button on the popup window. What's the method for this? I'm using c# and asp.net, and I don't know anything about jquery, so fair warning, answers using jquery will inspire even more questions. Which is fine as long as you don't mind answering :D

Sorry, this wasn't clear so I'm editing. I actually need to know how to *open the popup window* as well as cause it to close upon submission. Whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close your popup, you can use javascript `window.close();` function

and if you want to close in code behind in C#, then it will be...

```
Response.Write("<script>window.close();</script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *AjaxToolKit* [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx) control.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an actual popup window, as in a separate browser window, you'll just need to add some standard javascript to the page to allow it to close:

```
string strScript = "<script type=text/javascript>window.top.close();</script>"
if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientScript"))
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "clientScript", strScript);
}
```

Found here: [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1916&bih=930&q=asp%20.net%20close%20browser%20window&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=)

Add this code to the button click event handler, and it will close the window once it has rendered the javascript.